# Is there a way to alter the values of weight.output-prefix of edges with a script?

Tags: python, optimization, sumo

I want to optimize the flow of a simulated network to match the flow of a real network. I want to use the weight.output-prefiix or any other suggestions for the optimization. Can anyone help me go about it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to by weight.output-prefix at least there is no such option in SUMO. For calibrating have a look at https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tutorials/Calibration/San_Pablo_Dam.html

Comment: Is there anyway of optimizing a network in sumo? Maybe a different approach to optimizing a network